# Styling divs after using forEach() on an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I have an array of objects (myArray), I use forEach() to get back the individual objects, i'm trying to get each object's text displayed on the page but they are all appearing overlapped on top of each other. Is there a way I can style them so they appear uniform on the page? i.e spread out from each other?

```
  myArray.forEach(function(myArraysObj) {
  var text = $('<div></div>').addClass('text').text(myArraysObj.text);
  $('body').append(text);
```

Comment: This is a css thing. the `.text`class probably has position: absolute;

Comment: This code will not do what you've suggested due to the syntax error. Also, please include the CSS used (as Jonas points out).

Comment: I've changed the position from absolute, it's not overlapping anymore, thanks. But is it possible for each div made from the function to be styled individually?

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: .text {
    font-family:baskerville,'Libre Baskerville', serif;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:12pt;
    width:300px;
}

Comment: `.text()` is overriding the `.textContent` property of `<div>`. it cannot be styled. you have to style the div instead.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set the style individually using the nth-child pseudo selector in your css:

```css
.text:nth-child(1) {color: red;}
.text:nth-child(2) {color: orange;}
.text:nth-child(3) {color: yellow;}
```

```html
<span class="text">Some text</span>
<span class="text">Some text</span>
<span class="text">Some text</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, what about if you don't know the length of the array? i.e the length of the array changes every time you refresh the page

Comment: in that case you could set the style in your js directly:
`var styles = [{"color":"red", "font-size": "12px"}, {"color":"blue", "font-size","24px"}];` and then when you create the element:
`$('<div></div>').css(styles[index]).addClass('text').text(myArraysObj.text);``

To make this work you need the index in your loop:
`myArray.forEach(function(myArraysObj, index)`

Of course you'll need to have enough styles for each div, or just make them start reusing styles once they've all been used once.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var addedText=myArraysObj.text+'\n';
 var text = $('<div></div>').addClass('text').text(addedText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
  for (var x in myArraysObj) {

     var text = $('<div></div>').addClass('text').text(x.text);
      $('body').append(text);
    }
```